# Local storage saved from external domain javascript doesn't get saved under external domain

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage

If I load a javascript file from example.org on example.com and save something in local storage, it doesn't get saved under example.org (like how cookies would) but gets saved under example.com instead.

This makes it impossible for data to be kept on example.org like in the case of cookies. Cookies would work but they would carry the burden of being passed on along every HTTP request, which is what I want to avoid.

Tried looking up but nothing actually caters to the scenario of javascript being loaded from an external domain. Is this really by design? Doesn't sound like a good approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever browser-side JavaScript needs to care about the origin, it uses the URL of the page hosting the JavaScript to determine it.

This is the only reasonable way to approach it, because you would otherwise have a huge security hole.

Jo Evil Hacker would simply `<script src="http://example.org/yourScript.js"></script>` and then call functions in it to get the cookies which should be kept private from them.